# page dies when curl_exec and show ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl to get tokens from other service but it keep dies with no reason.

Since it dies, there's no output and no error logs. Just ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on chrome.

Here's my code.

```
$url = ".......";
$is_post = false;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $is_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);        <----------------------dies here
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "status_code:".$status_code;
curl_close ($ch);
```

I've done example below and it didn't accured any troubles.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

And when I printed $url and put it into browser, I think it works perfectly(shows what I need).

Does anyone has any clue???

**Update**

My curl version is 7.19. And It's definetly HTTPS issue since HTTP works fine.

I've tried

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/cert/file/cacert.pem');
```

and

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

but none of these worked.